# How to read function name from one lua script file?

Tags: c++, lua

I want to get the Lua function name,the Lua file is like:

```
function name_1()
   ...
end
function name_2()
   ...
end
```

I will never execute the lua file ,but execute c++ code to read it. In another word, lua file is just one string, and i need to parse it to get the function names, like:

```
name_1()
name_2()
```

When i get the names, i will save it, and use it to call the lua function in another step.

My question is : is there some library to realize such purpose.If not,should i use some text parsing methods, or regular expressions？

The easiest way I've tried is to read this file and look for the string "function" to get the name, but this way will inevitably encounter special circumstances. Can there be a better library to support this purpose

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you ,but i will not execute the lua file ,and only read it in c++ code and execute c++ code.

Comment: If you don't want to execute the Lua file then you would probably have to do your own parsing. Shouldn't be too hard since global Lua function declarations have fairly simple syntax. Alternatively, you might be able to jerry-rig the Lua parser to do this for you.

Is there a reason why you can't just use the Lua state to do this for you?

Comment: First please read e.g. [Lua C API: How to get a function name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52552237/440558) And with that in mind, what is the actual problem you need to solve? *Why* do you need the names (which doesn't really exist)? What problem is getting those names supposed to solve? Right now your question is very much an [XY problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52552237/440558).

Comment: And just to refresh (since I deleted my first comment): Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You might find [this script](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/e4ab3bfc777faf4482a1b3f3ae19181b) useful.  You need globals with W-access.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff This helps me a lot. I will try to read and rewrite it in C + +，thank you so much.